# Problem in JEFF LAMARCHE Objective-C export script for Blender

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, 3d, blender

Hi I was using Jeff Lamarche objective c export script, http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/02/blender-25-beta-6-objective-c-export.html .

But i am encountering a strange problem, whatever model i am rendering using this script, i am getting top view of that model on iphone. Is there any way by which i can render side view of the model??

I am building simple room with some walls. If needed i can supply the sample blend file.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you could post the blend file. Can you upload it here: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

At a guess, I would suggest rotating the whole model 90 degrees before using the script. Also make sure that you are clearing the rotation of the model.

Answer (score 0):

Jee LaMarche's script has been updated to work with the latest Blender 2.5. You can download it and install it easily [on his site here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/04/blender-257-objective-c-export-script.html).

I'd get Blender 2.5 release build, install the script, and import your previous .blend file in here.

There's an option to export as "Y-up" : "The second option will rotate the object 90° along the X axis, which converts the object from Blender's Z-up coordinate space to OpenGL's Y-up coordinate space. I've made this the default, but I could foresee situations where people would want to skip the conversion." (quoted Jeff's site).

Last, I would do what Sycren said and rotate the object 90 programmatically. For example, in your draw view method:

```
...
glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef(90.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // rotate 90 degrees on the y-axis
glScalef(1, 1, 1);
...
```